# 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax in Doctrine. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I don't understand, why my browser return this error and why my sql doesn't work. I try resolved this problem, but I don't know, how can I do this.

```
private function getFromDb()
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $queryBuilder
        ->select('art1.articleID', 'art1.valueID')
        ->from('s_filter_articles', 'art1')
        ->innerJoin('art1', 's_filter_articles', 'art2', 'art1.articleID = art2.articleID')
        ->where('art1.valueID = 12499')
        ->andWhere('art2.valueID = 12500');

    return $query->execute()->fetchAll();
}
```

This code return this array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "articleID" => "2225"
    "valueID" => "12499"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "articleID" => "2250"
    "valueID" => "12499"
  ]
]
```

...and I would like to delete ALL this result in MySQL. SO I wrote this code:

```
public function removeFromDb()
{
    $result = $this->getFromDb();


    foreach ($result as $option) {

        $queryBuilder = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();
        $query = $queryBuilder
            ->delete('s_filter_articles', 's')
            ->where('articleID = :articleID')
            ->andWhere('valueID = :valueID')
            ->setParameter(':articleID', $option['articleID'])
            ->setParameter(':valueID', $option['valueID']);

        return $query->execute();
    }
}
```

BUT my browser return this error:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 's WHERE (articleID = '2225') AND (valueID =
> '12499')' at line 1 in
> /var/www/html/strefatenisa.local/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php
> on line 131

> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing
> 'DELETE FROM s_filter_articles s WHERE (articleID = ?) AND (valueID =
> ?)' with params ["2225", "12499"]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 's WHERE (articleID = '2225') AND (valueID =
> '12499')' at line 1 in
> /var/www/html/strefatenisa.local/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php
> on line 131
```

EDIT:
If I do normal query in my mysql, all works good.

```
SELECT art1.articleID, art1.valueID 
        FROM s_filter_articles as art1
    INNER JOIN s_filter_articles as art2 ON  art1.articleID = art2.articleID
    WHERE art1.valueID = 12499
    AND art2.valueID = 12500

DELETE FROM `s_filter_articles` WHERE `articleID` = 2225 AND `valueID` = 12499
```

Comment: I don't know about doctrine but the correct sytax in MySQL is: `DELETE FROM s_filter_articles WHERE ...` or `DELETE s FROM s_filter_articles s WHERE ...`

Comment: Try simple `->delete('s_filter_articles')` without an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Update your function removeFromDb() with this code:

```
public function removeFromDb()
{
    $result = $this->getFromDb();

    foreach($result as $option){
        $queryBuilder = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder->delete('s_filter_articles', 's')
                     ->where('articleID = :articleID')
                     ->andWhere('valueID = :valueID')
                     ->setParameter(':articleID', $option['articleID'])
                     ->setParameter(':valueID', $option['valueID']);

        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

createQueryBuilder function returns a new instance of the QueryBuilder class which doesn't have any declaration of the execute() method. That's why I added the getQuery() method to return the Query class which is the one that has the execute() method. Another thing that I removed is the return from inside of the foreach. I hope this work for you, if not let me know and I can help you.